# Need to change blog url in shopify

Tags: shopify

I am trying to change blog URL in the Shopify store.
Currently, I am blog URL is like this https://example.com/blogs/news

https://example.com/blogs/news to https://example.com/blog/

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the URL structure of any of the Shopify pages.

Comment: This answer should be selected as the correct answer, straight to the point.

Comment: ... except for Shopify themselves it seems. See https://www.shopify.com/blog